# What Stats and Equipment increase damage from Hexes?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I current have INT 16, FTH 26, and am using Resonant Soul with an Idol's Chime +1.

What do I need to level up, in order to increase the damage from Resonant Soul? Do I Level Up Intelligence, or Faith, or does reinforcing the Chime increase the damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dark damage scaling is determined by the lower of your Faith and Intelligence stats. So, you would have to increase your intelligence first to increase your dark scaling.

As for the Chime, reinforcing it would also increase the dark damage it does.

Source: http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Dark

Comment: Post note: if both your Faith and Int stats are equal, you can effectively double the damage output.